# Detect a double "overflow"?

Tags: c++

I know that for big and small numbers double use scientific notation to store them. I wanted to create a function that given a string input could detect if that string is a double and it's not over or under double representation limit.

This following I tried to do does the job, but if i give a string input it returns true:

```cpp
#import <limits>
#import <iostream>
#import <sstream>
#import <string>

bool isdouble(const string& str) {
    istringstream ss(str);
    double num;

    ss >> num;

    if (!ss.fail()) {
        return false;
    }
        
    return (num >= numeric_limits<double>::lowest() && 
            num <= numeric_limits<double>::max());
}
```

What can I do to make it work fine with string inputs too?

Comment: Your `if` is backwards. You are returning `false` if the `string` is *successfully* parsed into a `double`. You need to remove the `!` when checking `fail()`, eg: `if (ss.fail())`.  Alternatively, you can use `if (!ss)` or better `if (!(ss >> num))` instead to check for parsing errors.

Comment: The limits to variables exist usually because the CPU hardware used can't physically hold a larger or smaller number so the comparison to figure out if its larger or smaller than the limit can't work.

Comment: a `double` can never be smaller than the smallest number a `double` can be

Comment: With your updated `if` it returns `false` for a string. You could add `if(ss.peek() != EOF) return false;` after that to prevent `123abc` from passing as a `double`. Also, if you want to check the limits of a `double` make `num` a `long double`.

Comment: We probably should revert the question back to the original code since it has an answer that fixes the original code.

Comment: please do not fix the code in your question according to comments. Correct code should go to answers, your question is for the wrong code.

Comment: Howdy, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've reverted your edit to the question because it invalidated an answer that was correct with the initial wording. You have to be careful to not move the goal posts so much that the question and answers no longer align. Sometimes you'll find you've asked the wrong question as the result of comments or answers, but remember that your question will probably help others in the future.

Comment: and the last edit is also not taken into account by my answer. Please do not alter the question to ask for something else after you received answers. Honestly I am not willing to fix my answer, its not a complete answer for the question as it stands now, but it was one for the question as it was when I wrote it. Thats not nice, and I will revert also this last edit

Comment: You can open a brand new follow up question if you need to do so. Make sure to indicate the input and output and describe the new problem you have and show a [mcve]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm very sorry, I'm kinda new there and I didn't know I shouldn't.. I'm looking to your answer and I'll edit accordingly

Comment: The reason for all these requirements is StackOverflow is not a user forum. Instead its a Q&A repository and the #1 point of your question is to help future readers solve the same problem.

Comment: At this point I recommend that you stop editing, wait for the question-asking cooldown timer to to expire, and ask a new question about the current state of the code.

Comment: In general, use edits to clarify the question. Do not use them to change the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: Re “a `double` can never be smaller than the smallest number a double can be”: `lowest()` is not the smallest a `double` can be; it is the lowest finite value. `double x = -INFINITY; std::cout << (x < std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()) << '\n';` prints “1”.

Comment: Re: "for big and small numbers double uses scientific notation" -- if I'm reading that correctly, it's not quite right. `double` typically uses what might be called "scientific notation" for **all** stored values. On most systems today it uses a binary fraction and a binary exponent, with the value being fraction * 2^exponent. The fraction is always (oversimplification) less than 1 and greater than or equal to 1/2; the exponent is adjusted to keep the fraction in that range.

Answer (score 6):

Your check is wrong. `num` is a `double`. The maximum number a `double` can possibly store is `numeric_limits <double> :: max()`. Hence, `num` can never be larger than that value.

This

```
if (!ss.fail()){
    return false;
```

Is wrong, because it returns `false` when the extraction of a `double` from the stream does not fail. But the extraction fails when the string does not hold a `double`.

Your function can look like this:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

bool isdouble(const std::string& str) {
        
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    double num;
    return !!(ss >> num);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max() << "\n";
    std::cout << isdouble("1e100") << "\n";
    std::cout << isdouble("1e310") << "\n";
}
```

[Possible output](https://godbolt.org/z/b564zT435):

```
1.79769e+308
1
0
```

When the stream is in an error state its conversion to `bool` yields `false` (remember that `ss >> num` yields a reference to `ss`). This conversion is `explicit`, but I used `!` to trigger contextual conversion to `bool`, and `!!` to get the actual `bool` (I allowed myself a fancy way of writing `static_cast<boo>(ss >> num)`). Once extraction from the stream suceeds you need not check anymore if the value is in the range of `double`, because if it wasnt, the extraction would have failed.

---

PS: As suggested by TedLyngmo, to check if the whole string is nothing but a valid `double` you can change the above to:

```
return (ss >> num) && ss.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof();
```

This will make the function return `false` eg for `"3.141 is not a number"`, because after extracting `3.141` as `double` there are still characters left in the stream.

---

PPS: As Eric Postpischil pointed out, the above "Hence, `num` can never be larger than that value." is not quite correct, because `double`s can hold `+Inf` and `-Inf`. I don't know how to read them from a `std::string`, but if you want to exlcude them as "not in the range", they need to be taken into account in addition to the "can be extracted" check.

Comment: Re “Hence, `num` can never be larger than that value”: The common `double` format can represent ∞, and `max` is only the maximum finite value, so `num` can be larger than `max`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil nice. Can I read  ∞ from a string?  Via `"Inf"` ?

Comment: Yes. And you can also get ∞ because the string contained a properly formatted numeral that was so large it does not convert (with rounding) to a representable finite number. There are at least three cases of interest in this region: The string contains a numeral that would round to the next finite number in the format if its exponent range continued, the string contains a numeral even larger than that, and the string contains an explicit representation of infinity. OP needs to specify what limit they want to detect.

Comment: There is another case too that I have seen in the low end, if I recall correctly. On the high end, it would be this: The string contains a numeral that is greater than the largest representable finite number but that, when the ordinary rounding rule is applied, rounds to the largest representable finite number. Some library implementations might return an indication that is “out of bounds,” but it is reasonable to consider it in bounds and return the properly rounded result. Again, OP needs to specify what limit they want to detect.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) which is supposed to be *fast*:

```cpp
#include <charconv>

bool isdouble(const std::string& str) {
    double d;
    auto end = str.c_str() + str.size();
    return std::from_chars(str.c_str(), end, d).ptr == end;
}
```

`from_chars` a returns a [`std::from_chars_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars_result) that contains a pointer (that's the `ptr` above) to the first character "not matching the pattern" or the "end" pointer - so the above checks that it successfully parsed the whole string as a `double`.

Note: Some overloads of `from_chars` has a fourth parameter which relates to the format you want to parse. It's defaulted to [`std::chars_format fmt = std::chars_format::general`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/chars_format) (which means `fixed | scientific`) but you have the option to use another setting.